# 504 error when open the php page first time

Tags: mysql, wordpress, ubuntu, load-balancing, php-7

I have a website which is build in php. When I open some page its shows me 504 error( HTTP ERROR 504 took too long to respond) fist time after reload its working fine for me.

Here are my server configuration

Two unbuntu server running behind the azure load balancer.

1. Ubuntu 16.0
2. Wordpress
3. Php7.3
4. database MySQL 5.8
5. 755 permission given for folders
6. Folder owner www-data:www-data
7. Sucuri firewall
8. Stackpath
9. Load balancer

**request flow :
DNS-Stackpath (CDN)- Sucuri firewall - LB - Ubuntu VMs**

I have added 0 as max_execution_time and 512 memory limit for both server php.ini file.

Can anybody help me to fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is high chance that you didn't whitelist Stackpath IP ranges on Sucuri and Sucuri is blocking requests from Stackpath IPs

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: @Andronicus since I'm kinda new here can you tell me when should I use comment and when answer?

Comment: This is rather a suggestion what **might** be wrong. If you don't have a concrete solution, you should rather comment

Comment: Thank you! I'm 99% sure that what I said is correct since I worked for one CDN Company and we had such reports all the time but I understand what you mean. Thank you for clarification !